# Cloning Dictionaries in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a hard time finding the answer to this question. Say I have the following script (which doesn't work):

```
class ProfileCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/accounts/api/" + username)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
}
```

This is what `result` and `this.state.items` look like, respectively:

```
{last_login: "2020-06-25T09:50:24.218Z", is_superuser: "true", is_staff: "true", …}
```

```
{}
```

How can I make the `this.state.items` have the exact same content as `result`? Please assume that all variables and methods used have been declared.

Comment: What you have looks fine to me. Maybe you are trying to access `this.state.items` before the data is available? Please provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

how are you?
How is your render()? Can you specify more your question?
For me, the way to put the results inside the items is right, but it only sets the state and changes the content of items after rendering.
Below an example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: ''
    }
    this.urlImage = this.urlImage.bind(this);
  }

  urlImage() {
    fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
      .then( (res) => res.json())
      .then((results) => this.setState({ image: results }))
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.urlImage()
  }

  render() {
    const { image } = this.state;
    if (image === '') return <h2>Loading...</h2>
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Dogs!</h2>
        <div>
        <img src={image.message} alt={'Dog'}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry if you understand that I do not interpret your question correctly, but want to complement that render() was used as an example to show that this.setState() is asynchronous, so with render() you can use this change of state, or you could use componentDidUpdate() that is also executed in the state receives a new value.

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  console.log (this.state.items)
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

In fact, you need to specify a question better, because a simple "my status is like this and I wish it could be like" this not described, I hope you can do what you want. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I don't think inserting the render function will be helpful since that wasn't my point for this question as I only want to copy the dictionary object. The second thing is that I want to clone a *dictionary*, not a string. Definitely appreciate your attempt to help, but please read the questions clearly first next time.